# ko.utils.arrayFirst returning 'length' undefined on undefined object

Tags: knockout.js

For the longest time I thought `ko.utils.arrayFirst` skipped the looping if the first argument was `undefined` but say I have this :-

```
ko.utils.arrayFirst(undefined,function(){
    console.log("blah");
});
```

which throws an error as:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Has it always been this way or am I doing something wrong here?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q64FF/)

Comment: What made you think that? See https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js#L82

Comment: Just thought it should do a check before looping. :/

Comment: @haim770 you should turn that comment into an answer I think, closest OP's gonna get to getting one.